# infura web3.js get contract public variable

Tags: web3js, infura

I use this easy code to display the public variable of a smart contract:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    if(typeof Web3 !== 'undefined'){
        var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/MY_KEY"));
        console.log('Found web3!');
        startApp();
    }else{
        console.log("No web3!");
    }


    function startApp(){

        var SalesABI = web3.eth.contract([{ 
          // loads of lines
        }]);
        var SalesAddress      = 'address';
        var SalesContract     =  SalesABI.at(SalesAddress);

    displayETHRaised(SalesContract, web3);
    }

});


function displayETHRaised(_SalesContract,_web3) {
    _SalesContract.tokenRaised((_err,_resp) => {
        if (_err != null) {
            console.log(_err);
        } else {
            $('#DOM_ID').innerHTML = _web3.fromWei(_resp, "ether").toString(10);
        }
    });
}
```

I do not get the value of the public var and I don't get an error nor warning.

Everything seems to be fine but I do not get the value of the public variable `tokenRaised`.

Comment: Do you mean your callback gets called but there's an error in `_err`? Or it gets called with no error but the value in `_resp` is wrong? Or your callback never gets invoked? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [web3js-raw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw) which is a simple wrapper around web3js.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it the next day. The bug was somewhere else.

If someone want to use the code it's fine except do not use .innerHTML on the jQuery object.

Comment: yep, u should use instead ".html('aabbcc')"